# set text inside a check box

Tags: css, ionic2

Hi is it possible to add text inside check box replacing the tick icon.[image]

I am could not achieve it with this code could someone suggest me how to make a size selection box with a text inside it

```
<ion-col>
        <p>Choose the size</p>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-checkbox >S</ion-checkbox>  
        </ion-item>       
    </ion-col>
```

Help me to bring out this type of UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

check updated demo [here](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/gWJRpb?editors=1011)

Add the following Js to get the relevant radio value

JS:

```
$("body").on("click", "label", function(e) {
  var getValue = $(this).attr("for");
  var goToParent = $(this).parents(".select-size");
  var getInputRadio = goToParent.find("input[id = " + getValue + "]");
  console.log(getInputRadio.attr("id"));  
});
```

I assume that the user select only one size at a time. if user can select the multiple size modify the example with checkbox.

Try this

Check Demo [here](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/gWJRpb?editors=1100)

HTML:

```
<div class="select-size">
  <input type="radio" name="s-size" id="small" checked/>
  <input type="radio" name="s-size" id="medium" />
  <input type="radio" name="s-size" id="large" />
  <input type="radio" name="s-size" id="x-large" />
  <input type="radio" name="s-size" id="xx-large" />

  <label for="small">S</label>
  <label for="medium">M</label>
  <label for="large">L</label>
  <label for="x-large">XL</label>
  <label for="xx-large">XXL</label>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.select-size  input{
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  line-height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer
}

#small:checked ~ label[for="small"],
#medium:checked ~ label[for="medium"],
#large:checked ~ label[for="large"],
#x-large:checked ~ label[for="x-large"],
#xx-large:checked ~ label[for="xx-large"] {
  background: #999;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: any idea how to get its relevant value to a console after everytime any one size is been selected

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan Please check the updated answer. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 5):

You can hide the `input` and use the `label` to select the checkbox. Then style your label like in the example below, using `:not(:checked)` and `:checked` selectors. Same logic can be applied to `radio` buttons.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  clear: both;
}

li{
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked), 
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999%;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check_1" name="check_1" value="check_1">
    <label for="check_1">S</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check_2" name="check_2" value="check_2">
    <label for="check_2">M</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check_3" name="check_3" value="check_3">
    <label for="check_3">L</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check_4" name="check_4" value="check_4">
    <label for="check_4">XL</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```